# Fila de análise, respostas tardias

Tags: suporte

O que deve ser analisado na fila "Respostas Tardias"?

Existe alguma pergunta ou link explicativo sobre os procedimentos na fila de análise?

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Relação entre votos e Primeira Publicação/Respostas Tardias](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5425/3635)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A ideia é analisar respostas que são dadas muito tempo depois que as perguntas foram postadas - meses ou anos.

Por vezes, essas respostas podem ser spam ou tentativas de se fazer comentários postadas por novos usuários.

Além disso, uma vez que esse tipo de pergunta há muito deixou de ter atenção, este é um mecanismo que tenta garantir com que a nova resposta seja vista por outras pessoas. Desta forma se for uma boa resposta, atrairá alguma atenção necessária e poderá requentar o assunto da pergunta, enquanto que se for uma má resposta, os analisadores poderão excluí-la rapidamente mesmo tendo sido postada em uma pergunta há muito tempo inativa.

Comment: Saquei...Faz todo sentido...